# php setlocale arabic strftime

Tags: php, locale, arabic, strftime

I've run **locale -a** on my server and can see that it's got Arabic locale settings installed:

- ar_AE
- ar_AE.iso88596
- ar_AE.utf8

However, if I set the locale via:

```
$locale = array('ar_AE', 'ar_AE.iso88596', 'ar_AE.utf8', 'ar');
setlocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
```

and output it:

```
strftime('%A %d %B', $current_date)
```

The displayed date is in English, not Arabic.

Arabic is the only language this isn't working for: the site I'm working on is in 15 languages and all the others display a translated date.

What's going wrong?

Comment: What was the return value of `setlocale()`? Any PHP warnings/errors generated?

Comment: How about just `setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ar_AE');`?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me with no problems at all.

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ar_AE.utf8');
```

If this does not work, then there is another code in your PHP file that interferes with the language.

Comment: I tried it but it gave me latin names. The idea is to get translated names

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed this is for dates not names.

Comment: Week  days and months names